# StrToFloat raise error in my Application not in any application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My application written month ago in Delphi 7.
Now I want to convert a float str value (like 12.5) to extended, but delphi raise an error.

Debugger Exception Notification

Project Educatee.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''12.5' is not a valid floating point value'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Same function work correctly in New Application

Code is simply 
var 
x: Extended;
and any where
X:= strToFloat('12.5');

Comment: My answer was based on an incorrect reading of the error message. But please, show the code you're using, and the exact input that causes the error.

Comment: I found this error became after creating a special form. means if I prevent creating that form, strToFloat work correctly.!!!

Comment: Why not just assign the number directly: x := 12.5; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the value of **DecimalSeparator** variable located in *sysUtils* anywhere of your codes that is set to another character.
I found it and that was set to **'/'** character.